# Creating Local AMP Application on Network Share

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, mysql, php

I've recently begun to develope web applications with Apache web server, MySQL database server and PHP. My work is looking for a cheap efficient way to update an older split Access database which currently is configured with the backend residing on a network share and the front-end being distributed to end users.

Is it possible to install an AMP stack on a network drive and have multiple users at different locations access a php site on an Apache web server backed by a MySQL server. Could the end users simply access the site through the IP address of the network drive?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in addition to your PHP site using MySQL, it also needs to modify an access database.

Your network share resides on a server. So you wouldn't be installing AMP on the share, but on the server that the network share resides on.

You can either install AMP on the server that hosts the network share (Using WAMP, XAMP, etc. assuming it's a windows server), or you can setup a separate LAMP/WAMP server that connects to the network share the same way your users do. End users would access the IP or hostname of whatever server you have Apache on.

Comment: Eric thank you for your feedback!! The main goal of this project is to spend as little money as possible so would it make much difference in your opinion whether we installed the stack on the same physical server as the network share or simply installed it on the local HD of a workstation since the end-users will be accessing the application through the IP address?

Comment: It would make more sense to put it on the machine running the network share.